# Relationship in EF Core6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-6.0

I am just testing Net 6, in a test Blazor application I have the following classes and I relate it one to many with EF Core 6, however when I want to perform a POST to save in the database, it asks me to include the model from the foreign key, doing it in Net Core 3.1 everything works fine but in Net 6 I get the following error, am I missing something in EF6?

The models

```
 public class DatosPersonales
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset FechaRegistro { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string PrimerApellido { get; set; }
        public string? SegundoApellido { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string RFC { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Homoclave { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string CURP { get; set; }
        [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
        public int PaisNacimientoId { get; set; }
        public CatPais PaisNacimiento { get; set; }
    }



public class CatPais
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Pais { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Codigo { get; set; }
        public ICollection<DatosPersonales> DatosPersonales { get; set; }
    }
```

The Controller

```
 public async Task<ActionResult<int>> Post(DatosPersonales datosPersonales)
        {
            context.DatosPersonales.Add(datosPersonales);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return datosPersonales.Id;
        }
```

The JSON POST

```
{"Id":0,"UserId":"613544e8-ff4f-40cc-9389-10fcd8aa5b35","FechaRegistro":"0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00","Nombre":"Jhon","PrimerApellido":"Brown","SegundoApellido":null,"RFC":"BRJO56GT19","Homoclave":"ER2","CURP":"BRJO56GT19HYT4521E","PaisNacimientoId":1}
```

The result of the POST

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-58d58c01790a68cfb7f75c94f5bb637d-8f8db8b15825726d-00",
    "errors": {
        "PaisNacimiento": [
            "The PaisNacimiento field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by adding that allows the property to be null

```
public class DatosPersonales
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset FechaRegistro { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string PrimerApellido { get; set; }
        public string? SegundoApellido { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string RFC { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Homoclave { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string CURP { get; set; }
        [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
        public int PaisNacimientoId { get; set; }
        public CatPais? PaisNacimiento { get; set; }
    }
```